# What's the best way to upload 1,000 (different) content files to a GAE Java web app every day?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload

I need to upload a large number of content files to an App Engine app every day - perhaps 1,000 or more - that will be served from the app. Cumulatively over time I expect these uploads to add up to over 1,000,000 separate content files stored in the production app.

Is the `appcfg` tool the best or only way to carry out these daily batch file uploads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) is your friend.

Comment: That's what he says, when he's not telling me to burn things.